# J2ME application how many mobile supports

Tags: java-me

I need to develop mobile application, so I decided to develop the application on J2ME.

This application must be support for Blackberry mobile, in this application we are using google maps, so can I use the J2ME software and if I develop the application in j2me how many types of mobile can support my application?

If any better software is there for supporting different mobile please suggest me.

I already developed the  application in Android, this software supports few mobile, so I need to develop the application which mobiles are not supporting the android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J2ME used to be the most widely deployed runtime on mobile phones wordwide (it may still be, depending on when you read this and the amount of Android phones sold by then).

These days, there are many phones that don't support it:
- closed phones (they don't let you install any application)
- Android
- iPhone
- BlackBerry 10
- The Palm WebOS phones
- I don't know whether the Samsung Bada phones support J2ME
- I expect that most of the mobile linux handsets (Maemo, Meego, Limo, Sailfish...) don't include J2ME by default. They tend to prefer a port of the Android runtime
- ...

The problem in developing an application that needs to support many handset models in many different countries is J2ME's curse: the dreaded fragmentation.

J2ME itself usually means the JSR-118 specification, along with a whole bunch of other optional APIs specified in JSR-75, JSR-82, JSR-120, JSR-135, JSR-139, JSR-172, JSR-177, JSR-179, JSR-180, JSR-184, JSR-185, JSR-205, JSR-211, JSR-226, JSR-229, JSR-234, JSR-238, JSR-239, JSR-248, JSR-256. You can see them all [here](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/platform?listBy=1&listByType=platform).

These specifications have been interpreted differently by different companies implementing J2ME and they are often too generic to ensure the same piece of code to work identically on different phones.

Different mobile network operators also impose different requirements that sometime force mobile phone manufacturers to change the way their implementation of J2ME works based on who subsidizes the handset.

Operators can also modify data that goes through their mobile network.

Comment: "There are still phones that don't support it:" just want to add most of them never will. J2me is a dieing a slow and painful death, sadly it is just dying way to slowly :)

Comment: There are J2ME runtimes/emulators available for most platforms nowadays